# How do I write a value to the registry on a Windows Mobile 5 device?

Tags: c#, windows, string, windows-mobile, ipc

I have a string value that I want to write to the registry as a Dword to read via another program. How can i create a new key/string using c# .net?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be doing IPC through the registry? Perhaps you should check this out: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/ec71b672-e672-45d0-b32d-7ba134c4f779/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Microsoft.Win32.Registry to add to the mobile device registry.  All of the methods have mobile support: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry_members.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Using the Microsoft.Win32.Registry classes, [just like on the desktop](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives2/archive430.html).  There is one caveat: if you're using CF 1.0 then the classes don't exist.  In that case I'd recommend pulling the implementation from the [old SDF 1.4 source](http://www.opennetcf.com/FreeSoftware/SDF14/tabid/91/Default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class:

[Microsoft.Win32.Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx)

it is supported in .NET Compact Framework  3.5 and 2.0

The following links may help you:

[How to: Create a Key In the Registry (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e7chcf.aspx)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/PocketRegistry.aspx